# A question about Integrability and Uniform Continuity

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, uniform-continuity

I got this questions:

Prove or disprove by a counterexample the following statements:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function that is integrable on every closed interval and let $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\;dt$.
(1) If $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, Then $F$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
(2) If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, Then $F$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Some hints will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Only one of the two statements is true. The other can be disproven using very simple functions.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I took $f(x)=2x$ and showed that $F(x)=x^2$ which is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and (2) disprooved.